# Ordering allIds array with slice reducer

Tags: redux

I have the following structure:

```js
{
  todos: {
    byId: {
      123456: {
        id: 123456,
        text: "Hello World",
        dateTime: "2019-01-21T06:15:53.300Z"
      },
      ...
    },
    allIds: [123456, ...]
  }
}
```

Then I use slice reducer as described [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/updating-normalized-data#slice-reducer-composition).

```js
const byId = createReducer({})({
  [ADD]: (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state, [payload.id]: payload
  })
})

const allIds = createReducer([])({
  [ADD]: (state, { payload }) => [ 
    ...state, payload.id
  ]
})

export default combineReducers({ byId, allIds })
```

How would you handle ordering by date here? Because allIds reducer only gets the state (the array) and the new added object with its date.

The website linked above just says "Arrays of IDs should be used to indicate ordering.".

I can make a new entry in the state named `orderedTodoIds` for example but then the sentence above is not correct.

Comment: the question isn't clear to me. You want to keep the order of todos? Because it looks like you're doing it by default. When you add a new item then it is added to the last place in the list and that's good enough, isn't it?

Comment: @boaz_shuster Sorry for the unclear question. I added a date field to the todos state now. This could also be a "order": 1 or whatever.